# Cannot install GRUB on disk after installing Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

**Background**

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 on a 120GB SSD and Windows 10 on a 500 GB NVME for gaming.

I had to re-install the Windows operating system and now I **cannot boot into my Ubuntu OS even when I set it as the primary drive in the BIOS**. Instead it boots straight into Windows.

When I remove my NVME which has Windows on it, I get a Bluescreen.

**What Have I Tried?**

I was advised to load a Live Ubuntu version from a USB from a Reddit user: [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/o5eytg/cannot_boot_into_ubuntu_from_bios/)

I followed this tutorial: [tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

I've done slightly different things based on other threads, however it was essentially the same approach, obviously no luck.

**Problem/ Error**

- I booted into Ubuntu from a USB in EFI mode. Clicked "Try Ubuntu".
- Located my Ubuntu drive with `fdisk -l`
- mounted the `EFI` Partition with `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`
- Installed GRUB onto partition with `grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb`

Full terminal session: [Terminal commands/output on Paste bin](https://pastebin.com/uXH0Tkqe)

I recieved these errors:

```
# grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

Drive information from `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU655     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1F53C55F-A945-4522-B8CA-FB528B52CA1D

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  1050624 234440703 233390080 111.3G Linux filesystem
```

I really do not understand the issue here. I have read this brilliant thread: [grub2-install: “this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition”](https://superuser.com/questions/903112/grub2-install-this-gpt-partition-label-contains-no-bios-boot-partition)
where one response explained the difference between EFI booting and BIOS/legacy mode. Since I have a 512 MB EFI partition on my drive I am even more confused why this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

`grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb` was trying to perform a BIOS install. However, the drive already had an EFI boot partition.

**Solution**

Instead, `boot-repair` tool is needed to reinstall GRUB for the EFI partition.

If you want to use the GUI version of `boot-repair` follow this tutorial: [Boot-Repair, simple tool to recover access to your Operating Systems](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/)

Make sure to configure the advanced settings at the bottom and specify which partition the EFI System is on.

**Source**

All credit goes to [oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred) who help me a few days ago on a post and after a few more hours of research, I was able to interpret the documentation.